ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+ when starting jupyter lab
When running jupyter lab, I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import (
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .handlers import LabConfig, add_handlers
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/handlers.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .listings_handler import ListingsHandler, fetch_listings
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/listings_handler.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    "urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently "
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168

However, I installed OpenSSL 1.1.1
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1y  04 JUN 2024

Then I reinstalled python 3.12.3, pip installed jupyterlab and tried opening jupyter lap - didn't help. What else should I be doing?
I reviewed this, this and used this to install the OpenSSL 1.1.1. Downgraded by urllib3 version too, but nothing helps.

and used this to install the OpenSSL 1.1.1  Oooof.  It hurt to read that link.  How To Install OpenSSL 1.1.1 on CentOS 7  Ummm, how about: yum install openssl11-devel.
